# Using anonymous and basic authentication in the same folder under IIS7

Tags: .net, web-services, iis-7, basic-authentication

I have a have Winforms client that uses Web services on a IIS7 (W2008)

The client will first access a first.asmx page with anonymous aaccess, then access second.asmx with basic authentication (over SSL). This works fine in IIS6 where I can set first file to have anonymous authentication and the second file to have basic authentication.

When I move to IIS7 there seems to be a problem having two different authentication modes in the same virtual folder. Does anyone know how this is intended to work?

I have thought about fixing this with ACLs but it seems tricky.. or maybe move the anonymous first.asmx file to its own virtual folder. Any thoughts?

Regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check this out
[Did you know: Enable File Level Authentication in IIS 7 / 7.5](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Enable-File-Level-Authentication-in-IIS-7-75.aspx)

you can manually set the Authentication by go to the Content View -> right click on the file and click "Switch to Features View"

optionally, we can directly add the authentication for individual web pages in the  applicationHost.config file

```
<location path="Default Web Site/iisstart.htm">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<location path="Default Web Site/welcome.png">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Regards,
Vivek.

Comment: I could not set the authentication on file level in the Features view (only folder level) but your applicationHost.config was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: the link you give just redirects to ad campaigns now.