# IIS7 is losing the authenticated user for cffileupload (CF10)

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, windows-authentication, coldfusion-10

On one of our intranet pages, I'm using `cffileupload` to upload multiple photos:

```
<cffileupload extensionfilter=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif"
              url="/submissions/photo_gallery.cfm"
              onerror="errorissue" 
              width="600" 
              addbuttonlabel="Browse..." 
              maxuploadsize="100">
```

The url for this tag points back to the same page where I process the images:

```
<!--- Define the upload path --->
<cfset upload_path = "C:\websites\images\photo_gallery\">

<!--- Upload all the files --->
<cffile action="upload" 
        destination="#upload_path#" 
        nameconflict="makeunique" 
        result="uploaded_file">
```

In IE and Chrome, this works. In Firefox, I get a 401 error.  It appears to be related to how the browsers authenticate.  IE and Chrome use Windows authentication while Firefox prompts when entering the site for username/password. Nothing shows up in the Coldfusion logs, but the IIS logs show this (with the IP x'd out):

> 2013-05-09 19:16:07 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx POST
>   /submissions/photo_gallery.cfm CFID=5546&CFTOKEN=75080018 80 - 172.28.30.99 Shockwave+Flash 401 2 5 0

The previous line in the log is from loading the page. As you can see, my username is showing up in this line (edited for security):

> 2013-05-09 19:16:07 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /includes/js/shared.js - 80
>   DOMAIN\username xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:20.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/20.0
>   304 0 0 218

So, cffileupload seems to be losing my username. However, the session.urltoken in the cffileupload url is the same as it is in on the page with the multiple file uploader (the calling page). So, you'd think the authentication would stick.

Also, I can get it to work in Firefox when I go into IIS7 and enable Anonymous Authentication on the Jakarta virtual directory (and disable Windows Authentication on the same).  But, this is not a usable solution.

Can anyone suggest another solution?

Comment: Is the browser prompting for the user's credentials?  How is Firefox "not working", is it returning a 401 or 403 status code?  What version of Firefox (and the other browsers)?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I should have mentioned that. It's prompting for credentials to get to the site. cffileupload is returning a 401 error. In the IIS logs, it shows the following: 2013-05-09 19:16:07 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx POST /submissions/photo_gallery.cfm 80 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:20.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/20.0 401 2 5 15   (I x'ed out the IP)

Comment: You should see a 401 for the initial request, that should force the browser to authenticate and prompt for the user's credentials. What do the logs show on subsequent requests (after passing the credentials)?  Also, are you including the domain name when supplying credentials "domainname\username"?  That is sometimes required for non-IE browsers with Windows Domains.

Comment: Once I authenticate on entering the first page of the site, I am not asked to authenticate again. It's just cffileupload that seems to forget that I'm already authenticated. I've tried both with and without the domain name. Both work to get me into the site, but neither works when cffileupload tries to upload. I can upload to the same directory in Firefox with a plain cffile. So, I'm thinking it has something specifically to do with how cffileupload works.

Comment: Are you using `cflogin` and/or session management?  I found a similar issue on [Ray Camden's blog](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/11/11/Important-notes-about-ColdFusion-9s-new-multi-file-uploader) (although it regards CF9). A couple others mentioned adding `?#urlEncodedFormat(session.urltoken)#` to your URL attribute. Have you tried that by chance?  Not sure if there are any security implications with adding that to the URL? The user won't see that URL...

Comment: [Found another post here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/3/5/ColdFusion-9-Multifile-Uploader--Complete-Example) that mentions you need to encode the entire URL and not just the session token. Like `<cffileupload url="#urlencodedformat("upload.cfm?upload=true&foo=bar")#">`

Comment: I've tried variations on adding the urlencodedformat to the url attribute with no luck. I believe the session management bug was fixed based on what I'm seeing in the IIS logs. But, I gave that a try as well with no luck.

Comment: Does your intranet have a fully qualified domain name?  Is it something like `http://www.ourintranet.com/` or is it like `http://ourintranet/` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Firefox to work with Windows Authentication as well.  It is not turned on by default ([reference](http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/)).

1. Open Firefox
2. In the address bar type: "about:config"
3. Firefox3.x and later requires you to agree that you will proceed with caution.
4. After the config page loads, in the filter box type: "network.automatic"
5. Modify `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` by double clicking the row and enter `http://www.replacewithyoursite.com` or `http://your-intranet-server-name`
   Multiple sites can be added by comma delimiting them such as `http://www.replacewithyoursite.com, http://www.replacewithyourintranetsite.com`

*To specify all subdomains use `.replacewithyoursite.com` instead of `www.replacewithyoursite.com, help.replacewithyoursite.com, pictures.replacewithyoursite.com`*

If your intranet does not use a fully qualified domain name you can set the following in Firefox to avoid the prompting ([reference](http://dirq.net/2012/11/firefox-windows-authentication-iis/))

1. Go to "about:config"
2. Filter the keys down to "network.automatic"
3. Edit `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn` value to `true`
   [image]

Comment: +1 This would be a great idea, but I need to leave it off Windows authentication. Plus this page is used by thousands of people in different setups, so I won't be able ask them all to make this change.

Comment: But you said in your question that turning off Windows Authentication was not a usable solution? You can modify the Firefox installer to make the settings for you (see the first reference).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I can't turn off Win Authentication in IIS because it creates other problems. But, I can't use Win Authentication for Firefox because I would have to instruct all users to follow the steps you provided.  Instead, I need a way for users to go to the site in Firefox (as is), enter their Windows login credentials when prompted, and then be able to navigate to and use the multiple file uploader. My understanding is the Windows login credentials should be saved with the session. But, cffileupload appears to be losing that, despite appearing to have the correct session.

Comment: Can you confirm if the above settings work? This might be the way to make Firefox "remember" the authentication credentials for each subsequent request.  At least you will know if this works or not. For an intranet you should have more control of your user's setup.

Comment: No, they appear to have no effect.

Comment: Can you also try to add your domains in the 'network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris' value also ? in the about:config settings. This is in combination with solution given by @Miguel-F

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling "Anonymous Authentication" just for the /submissions folder?

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config)