# Custom ASP.net webservice in Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, asmx

I have created one asp.net custom webservice in sharepoint 2010 using VS, i have deployed it under _layout folder of sharepoint. Everything works fine. Now i want this service to be exposed for cross domain, so any one can use it or call it also i want to be called from any non microsoft tech. like java....etc. the webservice add an item to sharepoint list i have written the code inside elevated priviliges.what else require to be done to make it availible for all or for specific people.

```
Now i'm trying to call same web service from console app, but i'm getting error below is my code in console app

            ListServiceReference.FRListWebServiceSoapClient obj = default(ListServiceReference.FRListWebServiceSoapClient);
            obj = new ListServiceReference.FRListWebServiceSoapClient();
            obj.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;

            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            // Use double the default value
            binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;

obj.WebMethod(parameters);

            Console.Write("worked");
            Console.Read();



And my app config is 

<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="FRListWebServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
                    messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"  />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://server name/_layouts/CustomListWebService/FRListWebService.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FRListWebServiceSoap"
                contract="ListServiceReference.FRListWebServiceSoap" name="FRListWebServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>


I tried increasing buffer size and all but no help. i'm getting exception


System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException was unhandled
  Message=The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<html>
    <head>
        <title>The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))</title>
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/_layouts/CustomListWebService' Application.<hr width=100% si'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)

What do I need to do at both end console app end and inside layout folder where webservice is deployed
Also I want it to be accessed it for cross domain for specific people in that scenario what are the changes I will require.

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: You probably also need to enable anonymous authentication on your web application. Have you tried doing this?

Comment: Not yet, will try this,anyways where can i mention this web.config?

Comment: You can try this post (http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010) to enable anonymous for whole web application. To allow anonymous using web config check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config)

Comment: It's better to deploy web services under _vti_bin. It's the place where other web services reside.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, now i'm able to call the web service remotly, and also i can consume it. now i want the web service to be consumed by SSL using https. when i tried this i'm getting error like the address is invalid... then i put security=transport in app config.     But the problem is it si saying No web application found at https://<servername>/sites/my spsite.  thogh i have given the path in app config is https://<server name>/_layout/web service name/.asmx...........any pointers??