# Anonymous access to aspx for some users

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp website.I have a page which is visible to logged in users only.My problem is i need to show this page to some one else with out logging in.Want to make it anonymous.How can i achieve this?

Comment: One option is to bypass Authentication module by User's remote ip. You can setup a guest account and give him pass if the IP address is your friend's.

Comment: @JonasT Is it possible to make the page anonymous from web.config?

Comment: Shekhar's solution will do but the will be visible to anyone without any restriction, not just your friend.

Comment: are you using form authentication?

Comment: You need to choose one verification method here, mate. Either IP address verification or private key via query string should work. Eg: give "yourpage.aspx?key=qpyehEWFTYf5wxzM" to your friend and you can check that key in your code and pass him through. In <authorization> section add <allow users="yourfriend@hisdomain.com"/>. When you bypass him, you need to set User.Identity(ticket.Name) with yourfriend@hisdomain.com.

Comment: See i have set my page as anonymous and passed a key as you said.But the page is not loading the style

Comment: It seems that your FBA is protecting all assets inside that folder. If it is OK for you to reveal any assets(images, stylesheets, js,etc) to public except .aspx files, set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" in module like <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">. If you want to protect those assets too, you need to allow every single resources(js, css, images, docs) used by that page of your friend.

Comment: Ya thats the problem.It may affect the security of the website.

Comment: Do the second part then, setup all assets used by that page with <location> for your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Create a guest account & log the anonymous user automatically to that guest account when he visits particular page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in you `web.config` file to show some file without loging.

```
<location path="yourpage.aspx">
   <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

It will allow for anonymous access.

Some links

1. [Allow anonymous authentication for a single folder in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config)

Comment: this will allow all users

Comment: Yes it will allow but what's the problem?

Comment: Shekhar's solution will do but the will be visible to anyone without any restriction- Jonas T

Comment: OP is asking for some users only not all, if page is visible to all then there is no sense for "login"