# CSS Not rendering on login page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am using forms authentication and a  sitemap file to define my roles but for some reason on the login page its not rendering the css and images so  my login page looks crap does anybody no what I am doing wrong been racking my brians for last hour with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<siteMapNode url="~/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" title="Home" description="Home Page" roles="*" />

<siteMapNode url="~/admin/student/default.aspx" title="Home" description="Home Page" roles="Administrator" />
<siteMapNode url="javascript:;" title="Admin" description="Admin Page" roles ="Administrator">
  <siteMapNode url ="~/Admin/Users.aspx" title="Users" description="Users Page"></siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode url ="~/Admin/Reports.aspx" title="Reports" description="Reports Page"></siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode url="~/Contact.aspx" title="Contact" description="Contact Us Page" roles="*" />
</siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

I am referencing my styles sheets as follows

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/main.css">
```

But when i click in the view source to see if the file is found it redirects me back to the login page so how do i make sure these files get ignored by auhtentication is the question i am asking?.

Comment: Make sure your web.config allows anonymous access to the /css folder. And probably to your /script folder as well if you have one.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10351155/736079