# Unable to view stylesheet in chrome

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

Tried to run http://localhost:30832/stylesheet/login.css but it returned

> This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web
>   address: http://localhost:30832/stylesheet/login.css HTTP ERROR 404

What is happening? I am very sure the naming is correct and it exists.

Comment: Which server should serve the file ?

Comment: @Niko what do you mean?

Comment: What server are you using ? Apache, IIS, VS builtin IIS Express

Comment: @Niko IIS Express

Comment: Are you running it currently. In other words have you pressed the play button

Comment: @Niko Currently no, but when I was testing, it is running!

Comment: It only serves content when running.

Comment: You could test if its mime related by saving an html document or stg to the same folder and try to load it

Comment: If you have enabled authentication, then you will need to allow anonymous access to the /stylesheet/ directory.

Comment: @Sam how do I do it?

Comment: @thompsonrapier Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075