# IIS URL Rewrite: Root Site Is Still Requiring Authentication

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-10

On IIS 10, I have a website at https://sub.example.com with a .NET App running on the root of the website that requires authentication.

I want to rewrite https://sub.example.com/MyDir to http://internalserver/MyDir. But have had no success with IIS rewrites.

I have ARR and Rewrite module installed-I've reinstalled the rewrite module.

Here is the rewrite rule on the website of sub.example.com:
[image: IIS Rewrite Rule]

The internal server does not require any authentication for "MyDir", but the issue is that the root site is still forcing authentication.
How can I prevent the root site from requiring authentication?

I've tried to follow this article among many others, but without success:
[Allow anonymous authentication for a single folder in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config)

**EDIT:** Anonymous auth is turned on, and here are the sections from web.config pertinent to authorization

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <px.core>
    <formsAuth loginUrl="Frames/Login.aspx" timeout="120" />
    <multiAuth>
      <locations>
        <clear />
      </locations>
    </multiAuth>
  </px.core>
  
  <location inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="None" />
      <authorization>
        <!--<allow roles="Administrator"/>-->
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="App_Themes/GetCSS.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="App_Themes/Default">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="App_Themes/Default/Images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Api">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="odata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="odatav4">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Soap">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Export">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Files">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Frames/Outlook">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Frames/PasswordRemind.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Frames/LoginRemind.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Frames/Error.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Frames/Maintenance.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Frames/PaymentConnector.html">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="calendarSync.ics">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Handlers">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="favicon.ico">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="EULA">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="robots.txt">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="CurrentWorkOrder">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You have to edit the question to show clearly how you configured authentication on that IIS site.

Comment: Please check if you have anonymous authentication enabled, if not, enable it. under IIS, double-click Authentication. The Authentication view opens. To login using your domain account, set the Anonymous Authentication option to Enabled by selecting it and then clicking Enable in the Actions menu on the right.

Comment: Edited and added the requested info.

Comment: You can try to add read rights to the Users group on the folder server.